# Use a list of subset indices in a for loop or function

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing groups of columns:

```
dataTab<-as.data.frame(matrix(data=NA, nrow=3, ncol=4))
names(dataTab)<-c("a1", "a2","b1","b2")
dataTab$a1<-c("d", "e", "f")
dataTab$a2<-c("d", "e", "g")
dataTab$b1<-c("h", "i", "j")
dataTab$b2<-c("i", "j", "k")
```

I manually build an aggregation table that describes how I wish to aggregate my data frame. The table contains the combined group names, and an index of columns associated with each group.

```
agTab<-as.data.frame(matrix(data=NA, nrow=2, ncol=2))
names(agTab)<-c("Grp_Name", "Index")
agTab$Grp_Name<-c("a", "b")
agTab$Index<-c("1:2","3:4")
```

**How can I pull the index values from my aggregation table to loop the creation of summary tables by group?**

In my first method, I use `cat` to remove the quotes around the index, as this is stored as `character` in the ag. table. This does not index correctly:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(agTab)){
  Ind<-cat(c(agTab[row,2]))
  print(Ind)
  sumTab<-as.data.frame(table(unlist(dataTab[,Ind])))
  print(sumTab)}
```

Result:

```
1:2NULL
[1] Freq
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
3:4NULL
[1] Freq
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I'm not sure what R sees as the index value, but the "NULL" is definitely not right.

But, I get the desired result when I manually enter the index:

```
sumTab<-as.data.frame(table(unlist(dataTab[,1:2])))

  Var1 Freq
1    d    2
2    e    2
3    f    1
4    g    1
```

and,

```
sumTab<-as.data.frame(table(unlist(dataTab[,3:4])))
sumTab

  Var1 Freq
1    h    1
2    i    2
3    j    2
4    k    1
```

**How can I pull the index from the aggregate table for use in creating my summary table?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a `split` into a `list` and then get the `table`

```
lapply(split.default(dataTab, gsub("\\d+", '', names(dataTab))), 
        function(x) as.data.frame(table(unlist(x))))
```

---

If we need a `for` loop, we initialize the `unique` `names` of the dataset ('un1'), create a blank `list` to store the output in each loop ('lst1'), loop through the sequence of 'un1', subset the dataset, get the `table` output and assign it to the output `list` element

```
un1 <- unique(gsub("\\d+", "", names(dataTab)))
lst1 <- vector('list', length(un1))
for(i in seq_along(un1)) {
    tmp <- dataTab[grep(paste0(un1[i], "\\d+"), names(dataTab))]
    lst1[[i]] <- as.data.frame(table(unlist(tmp)))
 }
```

---

If we want to pull out the index

```
lst2 <- vector('list', nrow(agTab))
for(i in seq_along(agTab$Index)) {
  ind <- eval(parse(text=agTab$Index[i]))
   print(ind)
   lst[[i]] <- ind
 }
#[1] 1 2
#[1] 3 4
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution that gets a desired result for the example I've provided. However, it avoids answering my question. Is there a way to call subset indices from a table to use in a for loop or function?

Comment: I've edited the question to be more pointed toward what I'm after. @akrun, I will use your elegant suggestions in a solution, but the main question is about getting an index out of a table to inform a function.

Comment: A little more work on the front end sets the data up for the first solution by @akrun.